# Smarty PHP remove specific text from a string

Tags: php, smarty

I have a string:

```
ćśóławegfdfsd
```

This string is with a polish char.

I want change this in smart on

```
csolawegfdfsd
```

In Smarty only.

Answer (score 3):

How about registering the following plugin:

```
$smarty->registerPlugin('modifier', 'translit', 'print_translit');

function print_translit($string) {
    return iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
{$var|translit}
```

This will transliterate the Polish characters. You may also want to append `//IGNORE` to the output format to ignore characters which can't be transliterated.

More info:

- [iconv PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)
- [Smarty registerPlugin() documenation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
$polish  = array('ć', 'ś', 'ł');
$replace = array('c', 's', 'l');
$text = 'A';
echo str_replace($polish, $replace, $text);
```

Comment: This isn't "in Smarty" but +1 for simplicity.